# Clearning values from function in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a form that reads in value from `sessionStorage` using [little-state-machine](https://github.com/bluebill1049/little-state-machine), but my tests are failing because state isn't being cleared between each test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

import { StateMachineProvider, createStore } from 'little-state-machine'

import MyFormComponent from './MyForm'

const goodState = { // some value }
const badState = { // some value }
 
describe("MyComponent with good data", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      createStore(goodState, { name: "TestState" })
    })

    it("should render with state machine values", () => {
      render(
        <StateMachineProvider>
          <MyFormComponent />
        </StateMachineProvider>
      )

      // tests here work
    })
})

describe("MyComponent with bad data", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      createStore(badData, { name: "TestState" })
    })

    it("should render with state machine values", () => {
      render(
        <StateMachineProvider>
          <MyFormComponent />
        </StateMachineProvider>
      )

      // tests here don't work and are using values from previous describe
    })
})
```

How can I ensure that the values from `createStore` are being reset on each test?

Comment: sessionStorage.clear() in beforeEach?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching for the same issue (as I was when I found this post), Estus Flask's advice is correct [Thank you :-) ].

From investigation there are a few options:

**1. beforeAll, beforeEach**

```
    beforeAll(() => {
        createStore(...)
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    });
```

**2. beforeAll, afterEach**

```
    beforeAll(() => {
        createStore(...)
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    });
```

**3. beforeEach, afterEach**

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        createStore(...)
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
    });
```

I went with `beforeAll` and `afterEach`, because my situation is not complex and my state doesn't change, and I want the reset to happen after each test.